# Check form fields on php

Tags: php

I want to check form fields on PHP. I have tried but I don't get any message. I am not sure why.

I use `mongodb` database, and I'm new in PHP.

**My PHP code so far:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
      method="post">
    <h3> Name :</h3>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="title/">
    </p>

    <h3>Title :</h3>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title/">
    </p>

    <h3>Content :</h3>
    <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>

    <p>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Save"/>
    </p></form>
</center>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    if (!isset($title) || empty($title))
    {
        echo " <h2> check title !  </h2>";
    }

    if (!isset($content) || empty($content))
    {
        echo " <h2> check content !  </h2>";
    }
}
?>

<?php
else: ?>
<p>
    success. _id:<?php echo $article['_id']; ?>.
    <a href="blogpost.php">
        write other articles ?</a>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: are you getting the title? try var_dump($_POST) inside if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) see if you are getting any values.

Comment: how i put var_dump ?  if (var_dump($_POST);isset($_POST['btn_submit']))

Comment: what is the output? do if (isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
             { var_dump($_POST);  }

Comment: you got a syntax-error in your if-else-endif. you need brackets (`{`) there!

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in if else statement and also there is undefined varibale $article['_id']. Where do you get that value from? Other than that the code is fine. Here is the updated code:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
      method="post">
    <h3> Name :</h3>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="title/">
    </p>

    <h3>Title :</h3>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title/">
    </p>

    <h3>Content :</h3>
    <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>

    <p>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Save"/>
    </p></form>
</center>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];


    if (!isset($title) || empty($title))
    {
        echo " <h2> check title !  </h2>";
    }

    else if (!isset($content) || empty($content))
    {
        echo " <h2> check content !  </h2>";
    }

    else 
    {
        echo "<p>Success!!! <a href='blogpost.php'>
        write other articles ?</a>  </p>";
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reviewed your code. I think it has a few problems, but the main one is in the if-else sequence.

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
      method="post">
    <h3> Name :</h3>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="title/">
    </p>

    <h3>Title :</h3>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title/">
    </p>

    <h3>Content :</h3>
    <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>

    <p>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Save"/>
    </p></form>
</center>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    if (!isset($title) || empty($title))
    {
        echo " <h2> check title !  </h2>";
    }

    if (!isset($content) || empty($content))
    {
        echo " <h2> check content !  </h2>";
    }
?>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>
    <?php echo $article['_id']; ?>.
    <a href="blogpost.php">
        write other articles ?</a>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: there is no message that appears when I write an empty article

Comment: The above code copy-pasted **EXACTLY** in a file foo.php and run BOTH on a local and a remote server seems to work without problems. Check this: http://goo.gl/GqK7SP

Comment: Its weird because i dont have any message what exactly code do you have copy ?

Comment: The code I mentioned on the answer. Double check it.